# Python crashes in rare cases when running code - how to debug?

Tags: python, debugging, hdf5, ollydbg, h5py

I have a problem that I seriously spent months on now!

Essentially I am running code that requires to read from and save to HD5 files. I am using h5py for this.

It's very hard to debug because the problem (whatever it is) only occurs in like 5% of the cases (each run takes several hours) and when it gets there it crashes python completely so debugging with python itself is impossible. Using simple logs it's also impossible to pinpoint to the exact crashing situation - it appears to be very random, crashing at different points within the code, or with a lag.

I tried using OllyDbg to figure out whats happening and can safely conclude that it consistently crashes at the following location: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ECbG.png[image]

It seems to be shortly after calling the python native PyObject_ClearWeakRefs, with an access violation error message. The weird thing is that the file is successfully written to. What would cause the access violation error? Or is that python internal (e.g. the stack?) and not file (i.e. my code) related?

Has anyone an idea whats happening here? If not, is there a smarter way of finding out what exactly is happening? maybe some hidden python logs or something I don't know about?
Thank you

Comment: What OS?  What is the exact error message?  (e.g. is it a segmentation fault?)

Comment: you can create your own logs, python has many logging modules, http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html for example - and then you can insert logging into all of your code (which - if it is a serious code for some company or whatever, would probably be smart anyway) - also - you should split your code into smaller chunks so you can more easily check the different parts. instead of passing variables through functions, write files and then read them, so in case of error, you can pick up where you left off.

Comment: Thanks. I did split my code into small chunks and also included logging. Unfortunately, however, the crashes are very random. The logger is not giving me a good insight into it, because it happens at a different point every single time. The debug output from the debugger, however, is consistent - which makes me think it's not hardware related to be honest. 

OS is windows 7 with python 2.7.2. There is no error messages, since python just crashes. The closest I was able to get was the OllyDbg output, which seems to imply it's an access violation error (see screenshot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers. I ran two versions this time, one with a new python install and my same program, another one on my original computer/install, but replacing all HDF5 read/write procedures with numpy read/write procedures.

The program continued to crash on my second computer at odd times, but on my primary computer I had zero crashes with the changed code. I think it is thus safe to conclude that the problems were HDF5 or more specifically h5py related. It appears that more people encountered issues with h5py in that respect. Given that any error in my application translates to potentially large financial losses I decided to dump HDF5 completely in favor of other stable solutions.

Answer (score 1):

`PyObject_ClearWeakRefs` is in the python interpreter itself. But if it only happens in a small number of runs, it could be hardware related. Things you could try:

- Run your program on a different machine. if it doesn't crash there, it is probably a hardware issue.
- Reinstall python, in case the installed version has somehow become corrupted.
- Run a memory test program.

Comment: what kind of memory test program would you recommend? why do you think memory might be affecting this?

Comment: In my experience, crashes that are intermittant have often been hardware related. Problems with e.g. the power supply voltages or CPU temperature tend to hang the whole machine, while RAM errors can affect individual programs. The most notorious sign is e.g. a C compiler dying with a signal 11. A good memory test program is memtest86+: http://www.memtest.org/

Comment: Hey Roland, I went ahead and used memtest86+ 4.2 and it passed once without errors after about 1.5h. =/ Do you think the debugging output is helpful at all? I get the feeling it might be h5py or thread-related..

Comment: The place where it crashes is in the python interpreter itself. Errors in Python code tend to result in an exception being raised. In my experience, python itself is pretty stable. Of course it can be crashed, but generally you have to make an effort to do so. Please try re-installing python or running the program on another machine.

Comment: I will re-install python - other machine is unfeasible at the moment unfortunately. I will post here if the error occurs again (or mark as solved if it doesn't occur anymore in the next 1-2 months)

Answer (score -2):

Use a try catch statement. This can be put into the program in order to stop the program from crashing when erroneous data is entered